# Can I disable the MAC in OpenSSL?

Tags: api, ssl, openssl

I'm doing some performance analysis on an SSL-encrypted connection and I want to tease apart how much time is saved by not MACing (I still want AES-CBC however).  Is there a way to disable just HMAC via the API?

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable it in SSL or TLS, period, regardless of the implementation. It is a required part of the protocol. Without it the protocol wouldn't be secure.

I did a performance study a few years ago that showed that over the Internet, SSL is only 3x as slow as plaintext. I was pleasantly surprised at that.

If you want faster SSL, invest in a hardware crypto accelerator.